# AUTO GENERATE ID C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to have an auto generated ID in adding students.

So these are my problems:

- If I display what has been added, `ID_NUM`'s are all the same.
- If I re-open the program, it should + 1 the last `id_num` that added.

But I don't know what I should do. :(

```
  class moon
    {

        int id_num;
        char name[100];
        char course[100];
     public:
        void add;
    }       

    void alt();

    void alt()
            {
                system("cls");

                char a;
                moon min;
                ofstream nimp;
                nimp.open("moon.dat",ios::binary|ios::app);
                min.add();
                nimp.write(reinterpret_cast <char *> (&min), sizeof(moon));
                cin.ignore();
                cin.get();
                heal.close();
                id_num++;

            }

        void moon::add()
    {

        cout<<"ID NUMBER: "<<id_num<<endl;
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Enter course: ";
        gets(course);
        cout<<"Enter name: ";
        gets(name);
    }
```

Comment: look for keyword static :)

Comment: Too many possible answer. A trivial one: save ID in file

Comment: so i added an `static int q;` outside of class nor global var. Should i use that one as id ? is that it? @zgrw

Comment: What do you mean sir @Garf365 ? My purpose is not to enter an ID # but to increment nor `+1` the last added `id_num` in `health.dat`.

Comment: 1/ Use a static `next_id` to assign new `num_id` and increment it after. 2/ Save value of `next_id` in a file and restore it value when you reopen software. --- **Warning** according what you have said, it's only _one_ possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct id_generator
{
    id_generator()
    : _id (0)
    {
        std::ifstream ifs("previous_id.txt");
        ifs >> _id;
    }

    ~id_generator()
    {
        std::ofstream ofs("previous_id.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc);
        ofs << _id;
    }

    int operator()() { return _id++; }

    int _id;
};

int main()
{
    id_generator idgen;

    std::cout << "next id is: " << idgen() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "next id is: " << idgen() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

example of use:

```
$ c++ -o idgen idgen.cpp
$ idgen
next id is: 0
next id is: 1
$ idgen
next id is: 2
next id is: 3
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but i'm getting `error C2252: '_id' : pure specifier can only be specified for functions`. btw, i am currently using visual c++

Comment: @ZayEyes enable the -std=c++11 flag. or modiy the code to intialise _id in the constructor. Member initialisation is a c++11 feature. c++11 is 5 years old. No-one should be learning in a c++03 environment any more.

Comment: @ZayEyes I've saved you the trouble. The updated example will now compile in a c++03 compiler.

Comment: Thank you sir @Richard Hodges . Yep, i know that it's too old but it's the school compiler. :(. Owe you sir.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are many failures in your code example. I hope that are results of copying.

You can't do this `id_num++;` in `void alt()`, because this isn't a member method of `moon` and `id_num` is a private member of this class.

Than you should use static for the `id_num` variable. You can have a look [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/) for an easy example. I think it's better for your understanding if you can comprehend a simple example.